# Connection to ground for a Cat5e Shielded outdoor rated cable

Tags: communication, ground, lightning, outdoors, ethercat

My ISP installed the cable modem in my entertainment room.  I am trying to have internet also in my STUDIO with an access point to broadcast a second WIFI from there to other parts of the house. (My property is big, with 2 floors, and concrete walls between since it is an old construction (50's) which decrease the performance of Wireless extenders, AP, etc (I tried everything, even Ethernet over power lines).  So, now I think I am left with running a Shielded Outdoor rated CAT5e from that entertainment room through the wall, then outside the house running up to the second floor and again entering the house through a hole to the STUDIO.  My question:

I have read that I have to ground any copper cable running outdoor before entering the house.  So, the GROUND ROD for my MAIN electrical box is next to the house, in a wall NEAR to my entertainment room (where the cable modem is located), so, I guess I can install an ETHERNET SURGE protector with ground connection that side of the house (exterior installed) to the MAIN GROUND ROD.  But what about when the CAT5e enters the house AGAIN in the second floor from outside through another hole in the Studio?  Do I have to install another ethernet Surge protector and run again a LONG ground wire from there to the Rod downstairs which is around 120 feet distance far?  Or, Is it ok to connect the cat5e cable to ground just in one point (the point leaving the house from entertainment room downstairs) which is near the MAIN Ground ROD of the HOUSE?

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement for grounding typically applies to cables which are AWAY from the building. Like cables the come in overhead from utility poles, or cables that come in underground.  The reason is that cables that are AWAY from the building are susceptible to lighting strikes, etc.  The few inches/cm difference from running on the OUTSIDE of the wall vs. the INSIDE of the wall doesn't put the cable at any significantly greater risk.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  good point.  The thing is I installed some IP cameras. Then according to what you explain, One of this cameras applies that scenario, since it is located in a distant point (the main iron gate, in a pole) which I run the cable UNDERGROUND via PVC conduit from there, then at the house point I installed an ethernet surge protector, which is connected to GROUND, before entering the house.

Comment: And since all the other cameras, which are outside in several points of the house (exterior walls) are running the same kind of cable (https://www.ubnt.com/accessories/toughcable/) but NO conduit.  Just plain cable through the outside walls.  
 Every cable has their own surge protector in the outside wall.  (the cable came with a drain wire)

Comment: But then I faced myself that I needed to run this new cable from the downstairs modem, to the upstairs studio all the other way of this big house and that is not a few inches.  I would say it is more than 120 Feet long run of Exposed Cable (over the roof or side walls).  and the ground rod where I connected all the other runs is located near the entertainment room (modem location)  rather than the studio (no near access to an external ground source from this point)

Comment: Is it ok just running the plain cable from one point to the other (outside walls, around 120 feet, and both ends entering the house) and just grounding the point which is nearer to the ground rod?  thanks again for any advise.

Comment: Yes, if you ground the lower point to the nearest ground, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally CAT5e cable is not shielded so you will have to make sure to buy the shielded variety if you want to shield it.

The best place to ground the CAT5e cable is to the chassis of the wireless modem. That works well when the wireless modem is AC powered with an three prong AC cord that then connects to a valid grounded three prong AC outlet.

If the cable equipment is not grounded at the AC plug then your better bet is to find a way to run the cable inside the walls.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Trust me, I tried inside the walls, but the constructions is old, and several mods and additions inside and technically, there is no attic either.  By the way, yes, the cable I bought was SHIELDED and outdoor UV rated:  https://www.ubnt.com/accessories/toughcable/      the cable itsel comes with a drain wire. And I bought small surge protectors that they allow to be connected to ground itself:  http://www.amazon.com/RiteAV-Ethernet-Protector-Lightning-Protection/dp/B00FY7GMEW?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01